# Do I do a insert or update max number into a existing column?

Tags: mysql

Example code

This is using update.

UPDATE `employees` 
SET `employeeNumber` = (SELECT MAX(`employeeNumber`)  + 1 
FROM employees);

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I not 100% certain but I don't think you need the subquery, try this:

```
UPDATE employees SET employeeNumber = MAX(employeeNumber) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. I needed to DECLARE a variable.

This is what worked:

SELECT MAX(employees.employeeNumber)+1 INTO yEmployeeNumber FROM employees;

Thanks for the response